# Example of a sequence $(s_n)$ such that the set of subsequential limits of $(s_n)$ is equal to the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$: math stack

Tags: analysis

1. Give an example of a sequence $(s_n)$ such that the set of subsequential limits of $(s_n)$ is equal to the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$
2. An example of a sequence $(x_n)$ whose set of subsequential limits $S$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: 1,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...

Comment: I am not sure if what I did is right, so I need suggestions.

Comment: 1. Let $S_{n}$ = {1,2,3,4,...},  $S_{2n}$ = {2,4,6,8,...} such that $n_{1}$ < $n_{2}$ < $n_{3}$ ... and $S_{2n+1}$ = {3, 5,  7,...}. Therefore, the set of subsequential limit = n                                                                                                            2. Let $X_{n}$ = {0,1,2,0,1,3,0,1,4,....}, $X_{3n-2}$ =0 and Lim$X_{3n-2}$ =o Similarly, $X_{3n-1}$ = 0 and the Lim$X_{3n-1}$ =0 Therefore, the set of subsequential limit = {0,1}

Answer (score 3):

Just choose any sequence which contains each element of $\mathbb{N}$ (or of $\mathbb{Z}$) infinitely often. Given any $c\in\mathbb{N},$ there is then a subsequence consisting only of this value $c.$ One such sequence is
$$
1,\,1,2,\,1,2,3,4,\,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,\,1,\dots,2^4,\,1,\dots,2^5,\dots
$$
which can be described by
$$
a_n = n + 1 - 2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor}.
$$